# Why does numpy linspace() function result in equally-spaced float values instead of integers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, linspace

```py
vec4=np.linspace(0,100,10)
print(vec4)
```

Running this results in

```py
[  0.          11.11111111  22.22222222  33.33333333  44.44444444
  55.55555556  66.66666667  77.77777778  88.88888889 100.        ]
```

Why is this not giving integers?
I was expecting this below

```py
[1    2    3    4    ..so on]
```

Comment: Does that array match the documentation?  Are there 10 elements?  Equally spaced?  Start and end with 0 and 100. Look at something smaller like `[0,1,2,3,4]`.  4 or 5 elements?

Answer (score 1):

When you call linspace like `np.linspace(start,stop,n_elements)`, you are telling numpy to create an array of length `n_elements` that have an equal distance and that include `start` and `stop`. Due to including start and stop, the space/distance is equal to `(stop-start)/(n_elements - 1)? which should explain the numbers you got.

If you just want integers, you can use `np.arange(start, end, step)`, however, this would not include end. Or, for you example, you can do `np.linspace(0, 100, 11).astype(int)`